# Returning dictionaries from methods

Tags: c#, generics, collections, coding-style

These types of methods have always bothered me.  Without digging through the code, I have no idea what the key or sub-value is supposed to be in this dictionary.  I've done this myself about a thousand times, I'm sure.  But it has always bothered me because it lacks so much information.

```
IDictionary<int,HashSet<int>> GetExportedCharges()
{
    ...
}

void GetVisitStatuses(IDictionary<int,HashSet<int>> exportedCharges)
{
    ...
}
```

Having the material in a dictionary makes sense, but all of the IDictionary methods have very abstract parameters.  I suppose I could create a new class, implement IDictionary, and rename all of the parameters.  It just seems like overkill.  Makes be wish c# had a 'typdef' directive.

How do you avoid returning dictionaries like this?  Or do you avoid this at all?

Comment: You should fill in the information gap with good method and parameter naming and plenty of comments, especially xml doc comments that can be used by intellisense.

Comment: @juharr - In general, I completely agree.  It seems to me in this case that the gap just might be too wide between these two method signatures for xml documentation to cover.  The only way one is associated with the other is by a similarly named parameter (luckily).  I'm definitely liking the idea of a new type here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very simple solution that you might find adequate:

```
public class IdToSetOfWidgetNumbersMap : Dictionary<int,HashSet<int>> { }
```

Advantages:

- Seeing a method returning an `IdToSetOfWidgetNumbersMap` doesn't leave many questions open
- The class can be left totally empty, or you can choose to provide aliases for the members exposed by `Dictionary` if you prefer

Disadvantage:

- You need to create a do-nothing class for each type of dictionary

Comment: I like this solution.  I'm thinking I might put the dictionary as a private member and just exposing the aliased methods.  In the end, it's all more work than I want to do just to get aliased parameter names.  But I suppose would rather compose more material that's cleaner than continue doing what's in my example.  Thx!

Comment: As well, this solves the requirements problem for the 'GetVisitStatuses' method.  With a strongly-typed 'ExportedChargesDictionary', there's no mistaking what needs to be passed in there.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't avoid returning dictionaries.

I agree, having only method signature it all looks very vague. So my rule is to ALWAYS write comments in a style "Dictionary (logical description of the keys) - (logical description of values)". And to hope that I will not need to use something horrible like

```
Dictionary<SomeType, <Dictionary<...>>
```

Comment: I agree.  The comments are required in these scenarios.  My bigger problem is with the 'GetVisitStatuses' method signature.  That signature is twice as vague as to what it actually requires for input.  If that parameter names didn't match, it would be impossible to know.  As well, I didn't write these methods, which makes it worse.  Dictionaries are so convenient, but so vague when used with primitive values.